# Как посчитать разницу в строках

Tags: sql-server

Доброго времени суток, у меня вопрос такого характера. Есть выборка в которой содержится 3 столбца и n строк (количество меняется) такого вида

```
1 столбец номер
2 время 
и третий какой-то count
```

Результат запроса

```
0128    2015-05-26 20:31:57.000 1

0128    2015-05-27 06:53:12.000 1

0128    2015-05-27 06:58:04.000 1
```

Вопрос у меня следующий. Как мне найти разницу между этими временами (datediff)? Если бы записи было 2 можно было бы вывести в одну строку как max и min время, но так как этих записей может быть гораздо больше... Может кто знает, буду благодарен.

sql Server 2008 r2

Мне нужно в итоге построить запрос типа case when datediff(mm, time1,time2) < 60 then... Построил свой запрос по вашей подсказке вот что получилось у меня

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE, @end_date DATE, @equip varchar(4), @shift_ident varchar(2)

SET @start_date = '2015-05-27'

SET @end_date = '2015-05-27'

SET @shift_ident = '1'

SET @equip ='0128'

;with cte as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY START_TIMESTAMP) num, 
    EQUIP_IDENT as eq ,
    START_TIMESTAMP as time,
    count(STATUS_CODE) as Zapravka
from EQUIPMENT_STATUS_TRANS
WHERE STATUS_CODE = 'O23'
    AND SHIFT_DATE between @start_date and @end_date
    AND @shift_ident LIKE '%' + SHIFT_IDENT + '%'
    AND EQUIP_IDENT = @equip
    GROUP BY EQUIP_IDENT,START_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT est.time, DATEDIFF(mm, est.time,est2.time) as duration
from cte est
join cte est2 on est.num = est2.num-1
```

выдает ошибку

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

исправил код... вот результат

```
2015-05-26 20:31:57.000 0
2015-05-27 06:53:12.000 0
```

выдает 2 строки и duration = 0  что не так?

Comment: Какую разницу? Если между строками n и n+1 - то нумеруйте и джойните пронумерованное само на себя.

Comment: `SET @equip ='0128'` - добавьте точку с запятой, как и говорит студия. Перед with нужно ставить `;` всегда. Можно для верности писать `;with`

Comment: `datediff(mm)` - разница в месяцах. Она 0 (обе даты майские). В чем разницу хотите считать? Если в минутах - то `mi` или `n` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна разница между строками n и n+1 - то нумеруйте и джойните пронумерованное само на себя. Пример:

```
create table #test (dd datetime)
insert into #test values ('2015-05-01'), ('2015-05-03'), ('2015-06-03');

with cte as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dd) as rn, * from #test )
select d1.dd, datediff(DAY, d1.dd, d2.dd) from cte d1
join cte d2 on d1.rn=d2.rn-1
```